# Is there a Paired z test function in python?

Tags: python, statistics

Does statsmodels have a paired z test to compare the mean of two dependent samples? I searched this page but couldn't find one.

Comment: hi ..check out this link https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/124096/two-samples-z-test-in-python

Comment: I had already found that, but there it only applies to independent samples (unpaired z-test)

Comment: paired ztest is the same as a one-sample ztest on the difference between the two samples.

Comment: so what you are trying to say is that paired ztest is calculated with weightstats.ztest(df['bp_before'], x2=df['bp_after'], value=0, alternative='two-sided'), but in the other post [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/124096/two-samples-z-test-in-python)  it says that weightstats.ztest assumes that the samples are independent. And this would be unpaired ztest.

Answer (score 0):

Since in paired samples you need to test if the mean of the differences observed between the measurments (called d) is different from zero (0) (the difference d is equal to 0 under the null hypothesis), you can use the statsmodels z test for independant samples:

ztest(x1, x2=None, value=0, alternative='two-sided', usevar='pooled', ddof=1.0)

with:
x1 : the difference d
x2 : None
value = 0 (the diffrence under the null hypothesis)